# Separate worksheet from a source sheet using Union in code problem

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook with 2 sheet in it.
One is called "Grouping" and stores many department names.
The other sheet stores staff record such as department name, age, name, salary....

I want to generate worksheets by using department name

When running this code, it only generates a sheet for the market department
and then throws an error. The error shows

> Method 'Union' of object '_Global" failed.

Can anyone tell me the problem causing this error?

```
Sub Extract()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng_Del As Range
Dim source_sht As Worksheet
Dim use_sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim gp_Lastrow As Long

gp_Lastrow = Worksheets("Grouping").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To gp_Lastrow

    Set source_sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    source_sht.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Grouping").Range("A" & a).Value

    sheet_name = Worksheets("Grouping").Range("A" & a).Value
    Worksheets(sheet_name).Activate
    Set use_sht = Worksheets(sheet_name)

    Set StartCell = use_sht.Range("A2")
    LastRow = use_sht.Cells(use_sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = use_sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, use_sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set Rng = use_sht.Range(StartCell, use_sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

    If use_sht.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        use_sht.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If

    Rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Grouping").Range("A" & a).Value

    'Delete hidden rows
    For Each myCell In Rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If myCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If Rng_Del Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng_Del = myCell
            Else
                Set Rng_Del = Union(Rng_Del, myCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not Rng_Del Is Nothing Then Rng_Del.EntireRow.Delete

    use_sht.AutoFilterMode = False
Next a


End Sub
```

After running the code, suppose the files should contains the following sheets.

> For example: Grouping, Sheet1(Grouping and Sheet1 is the origin sheets
>   tab in the files), market department(only have the staff record which
>   is related in market department), human resources(only have the staff
>   record which is related to human resources department), finances
>   department, cash control department

In the future there will be more departments added if the company expands.

Comment: even if i change to 
    Set Rng_Del = ApXL.Union(Rng_Del, myCell)
it will shows another error: Object required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing `Rng_Del` between sheets, so you're trying to union ranges between two different sheets: that's what throws the error.

```
Set Rng_Del = Nothing '<<<<<<< clear before entering the loop
'Delete hidden rows
For Each myCell In Rng.Columns(1).Cells
    If myCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If Rng_Del Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng_Del = myCell
        Else
            Set Rng_Del = Union(Rng_Del, myCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not Rng_Del Is Nothing Then Rng_Del.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: thank you guy! you are lengend! the problem is solved!! thank you very much